# Why did my SSH agent disappear after updating to macOS Ventura?

Tags: keychain, ssh, ventura

I recently updated my Macbook to macOS Ventura 13.1, and ever since that I've had trouble using SSH. This has always kind of "just worked", I've always been able to just `ssh` to a host and a popup would prompt me to unlock the relevant key. I've never given it much thought.

However, since I upgraded, there doesn't seem to be anything standing in for a SSH agent anymore:

```
$ ssh-add -L
Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory

$ env | grep -i ssh
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/gcr/ssh

$ file /gcr/ssh
/gcr/ssh: cannot open `/gcr/ssh' (No such file or directory)
```

I'm currently working around this by launching ssh-agent in the current shell:

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent)"
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/...
$ ssh my-target-host
```

I have Googled this to death, but it really seems like I'm the only person in the world with this issue.

As I don't really know how the SSH agent was working in the first place, I have no idea where to start looking. I suspect it was the macOS keychain?

How was this working in the first place, and why did it stop working?

Comment: woah you *don't* know how it was working in the first place? It looks like it's been messed with/tweaked pretty seriously for that... Not gonna be able to help you with how it was working in the first place, but maybe I can get it to work like it's supposed to (by default) without the workaround. First can you confirm that `$ which -a ssh-agent` only gives `/usr/bin/ssh-agent`? Then make sure that `$ launchctl print gui/$(id -u)/com.openssh.ssh-agent` says running, program is `/usr/bin/ssh-agent` with argument `-l`?

Answer (score 3):

Alright, it turns out there's a good reason I couldn't Google this issue. It was entirely self-inflicted. I sync my `.zprofile` and `.zshrc` files across all my computers, all of which run Linux except this Macbook.

Somewhat recently (around the same time as I updated the Macbook to Ventura) started using Gnome's Keyring SSH agent on my Linux machines. That involved adding this line to `.zprofile`:

```sh
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gcr/ssh"
```

This resolved to `/gcr/ssh` on the Macbook and overwrote the OS-provided `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable, which should look something like:

```sh
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.XJ4sRgc4gr/Listeners
```

I moved this line to a Linux-specific block like this, which fixed the issue:

```sh
# Very Linux specific stuff here
if [[ "$(uname)" == "Linux" ]]; then
    # ...

    # Gnome Keyring SSH agent
    export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gcr/ssh
fi
```

Comment: Ah that makes a lot more sense, I thought you had somehow installed gnome crypto and got it to work with keychain and I couldn't even imagine how you would do that